# Failed to send authentication request while using Flask and Ngrok

Tags: python, ngrok

I have a python code with Flash to test webhook listener

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def return_response():
    print(request.json);
    return Response(status=200)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def response():
    print(request.json);
    return Response(status=200)

if __name__ == "__main__": app.run(debug=True, port=4242, host='10.1.10.112')
```

It's running fine. But ngrok return error when I use `ngrok http 4242`

```
ngrok                                                                                                                                             (Ctrl+C to quit)                                                                                                                                                                  
Session Status                reconnecting (failed to send authentication request: session closed)                                                                
Version                       3.3.0                                                                                                                               
Latency                       -                                                                                                                                   
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                  
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                                         
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

I don't know what's wrong with this. Someone help me, please!!!

Edit: When run `ngrok diagnose` it return some warning and error like

> Testing ngrok connectivity...
>
> Internet Connectivity   Name Resolution                           [ OK
> ]   TCP                                       [ OK ]   TLS
> [ WARN ]
>
> Errors and warnings encountered during diagnostics:
>
> - Diagnostics   * Connectivity
>
>   - Err: Failed to establish internet connectivity: could not establish any
>     TLS connections
>     (NGROK_ERR_8001)
>
>   - google.com (142.250.207.78:443)
>
>     - Err: Failed to establish TLS connection to 142.250.207.78 with error:
>       context deadline exceeded. Possible Man-in-the Middle.
>       (NGROK_ERR_8003)
>   - google.com (142.250.66.78:443)
>
>     - Err: Failed to establish TLS connection to 142.250.66.78 with error:
>       dial tcp 142.250.66.78:443: i/o timeout. Possible Man-in-the
>       Middle.
>       (NGROK_ERR_8003)
>   - google.com (142.250.66.46:443)
>
>     - Err: Failed to establish TLS connection to 142.250.66.46 with error:
>       dial tcp 142.250.66.46:443: i/o timeout. Possible Man-in-the
>       Middle.
>       (NGROK_ERR_8003)
>
> Error establishing ngrok connection: Failed to establish internet
> connectivity: could not establish any TLS connections (NGROK_ERR_8001)
> Report written to /tmp/ngrok-diagnose3756442921/diagnose.json

Comment: What do you see when you run `ngrok diagnose`?

Answer (score 0):

From the diagnose output it looks like there are issues connecting to the ngrok service. Your network firewall, or something else, may be blocking the connection. You could also try to change the server address with this command:

`ngrok config add-server-addr=tunnel.ngrok.com:443`

You could also run the following to get more detailed output on the issue:

`http 4242 --log-level debug --log stdout`

Let us know if either of those commands help.